# Kodi jsonrpc know if an episode has been see

Tags: json-rpc, xbmc, kodi

I trying to retrieve a list of episode of a TV Show on my Kodi jsonrpc api, it return the list of episode but only id and name instead of all attributs show in the doc http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API/v8#Video.Details.Episode

Here is my request :

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"VideoLibrary.GetEpisodes","params":{"tvshowid":11}}`

And here is the response : 

`{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "episodes": [
      {
        "episodeid": 303,
        "label": "4x01. Success Failure"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 318,
        "label": "4x02. Terms of Service"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 339,
        "label": "4x03. Intellectual Property"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 354,
        "label": "4x04. Teambuilding Exercise"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 393,
        "label": "4x05. The Blood Boy"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 414,
        "label": "4x06. Customer Service"
      },
      {
        "episodeid": 487,
        "label": "4x07. The Patent Troll"
      }
    ],
    "limits": {
      "end": 7,
      "start": 0,
      "total": 7
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the params array add this `'properties': ['season', 'episode', 'playcount']` for example

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"VideoLibrary.GetEpisodes","params":{"tvshowid":11, "properties": ["season", "episode", "playcount"]}}`

This will add the three properties to the response.

Comment: Thanks ! That was I missing ! I was thinking it should send every fields :)